# Is there a way I can use inline styling and CSS class at the same time?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to do some styling for a page on BigCommerce platform, and for some components, I cannot find the styles and/or I don't want to mess with them.
for an `img` inside a `div` as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 saleBanner"><a href="https://www.MyURL.com/product-sale"><!-- pagebreak --><img class="SaleCategory" src="https://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/s-mystore/product_images/uploaded_images/myimg.png" alt="" /></a></div>
```

I tried to add style=`"border-radius: 50%"` to the `div` tag, and nothing changed. I'm not sure if it doesn't work this way or the built-in "editor" that I'm using on that platform just wouldn't allow me to do that for whatever reason.
I know this may not be the proper way to style a component, but what would be the best method for styling elements on a page that is already styled?

Thank you

Comment: editors normally strip stuff out to make safe; do your research first before coming to SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, this is what you're trying to accomplish?

```css
.saleBanner{
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="saleBanner" style="border-radius: 50%;">

</div>
```

Inline css styles will overwrite external css styles because they are more specific. Make sure you are including your semicolons in your inline styles as well, those are still necessary.

Comment: yes sir! I know this looks like a horrible development practice. But yah.

Comment: Makes sense. I was wondering if inline style overwrites external styles or merges with them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with using = instead of :

You tried: `style="border-radius=50%"`

Try instead: `style="border-radius: 50%"`

Comment: That was a typo in my question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously inline styles work at the same time with external style classes. I just couldn't see the rounded corners because the `border-color` was white. Thanks guys for your help.